# Updating Div with AngularJS

Tags: html, css, angularjs, data-binding, angular-ngmodel

I have a DIV defined as follows:

```
    <button ng-repeat="message in user.messages">

    <div ng-model="message" ng-show="{{message.received && !message.read}}" class="btn bg-green"></div>
    <div ng-model="message" ng-show="{{message.received && message.read}}" class="btn bg-green" ></div>
    <div ng-model="message" ng-show="{{!message.received}}" class="btn bg-amber"></div>
```

Basically I'm changing (show/hide) an icon depending on the message status (received, sent, read).
However, when I update the status of the message, the icons do not change, even though I have bound it with ng-model. I need to refresh the whole page to get the icons updated.

Any way I can do this update through Angular?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have more angularjs code you could show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. ng-show doesn't need to be interpolated, you can just write "message.recieved..."
2. why not use ng-class like this:

   div ng-class="{'bg-green' : message.recieved, 'bg-amber': !meessage.recieved}"

Don't bind div to ng-model, it doesn't make any sense to use 2 way data binding, when it is not an input, and the view can't update the model

Comment: Thank you Kobi. ngClass is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are binding all three div elements to ng-model when they don't need to be. ng-model should only be bound to input, select, textarea, or another custom input. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

Using ng-class should solve this issue without the need for 3 separate divs. It will allow you to dynamically change the class based on different expressions. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

```
<div ng-class="{'bg-green': message.received && !message.read, 'bg-amber': !message.received}"></div>
```